# Operator < doesn't seem to support "Any" type How to fix it?

Tags: scala, generics, operator-overloading

The following is a quick-sort function written in Scala to sort a list of mixed types(int, double, float etc.). The error popped out and said in line 3 "Type mismatch, expected: T => Boolean, actual: T => Any Cannot resolve symbol <". How do I fix this?

The Intellij IDE running on Windows 10 gave this error message.

```
    def qsort[T](list: List[T]): List[T] = list match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case pivot :: tail =>
        val(smaller, rest) = tail.partition(_ < pivot)
        qsort(smaller) ::: pivot :: qsort(rest)
    }
```

Comment: How would you compare arbitrary types? `T` needs to be a `Comparable` type if you want to compare it.

Comment: In C++, comparable types don't not need to be specified as long as they have operator < <= etc. But i am not familiar with the mechanism in Scala.

Comment: C++ checks for `<`  etc. when you **call** the generic function, but Scala does this check when it **compiles** the function. Scala needs to be sure it will work for all possible `T`, so you need to restrict the allowable types somehow. You can restrict the type itself, or add an `implicit` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Dmytro's answer will work for any type that can be implicitly converted to `Ordered[T]`. This is a bit peculiar, and in idiomatic Scala, people often prefer to use an implicit `Ordering` instead. This way, the order is completely separated from the implementation of `T`.

```
def qsort[T : Ordering](list: List[T]): List[T]
```

The signature uses a context-bound, and `[T: Ordering]` is syntactic sugar for the more verbose

```
def qsort[T](list: List[T])(implicit ev: Ordering[T]): List[T]
```

If you come from Java, `Ordering` is to `Ordered` what `Comparator` is to `Comparable`. Note that `Ordering[T]` is in spirit very similar to `T => Ordered[T]`, but I think it is simpler to wrap your head around when you're a beginner. It also gives you a nice set of methods to create and manipulate `Ordering`s.

Finally, note that using `List` for a sorting method like quick sort will result in really poor performances, because appending to a `List` is `O(n)`. If performance is a concern, use an `Array` with an in-place implementation of quicksort.

Comment: With your fix the syntax TS used `_ < pivot` works only after `val ev = Ordering[T]`
   `import ev._`

Answer (score 0):

Add implicit parameter

```
def qsort[T](list: List[T])(implicit ev: T => Ordered[T]) = ...
```